# Automating a command line with increasing file number

Tags: batch-processing

I am very new to creating batch files.

I have to run a command, with an increasing file number e.g

c:>program.bat -propertyfile "1.property"

Right now, I have to type the command manually, wait 1 minute, then type the command again by increasing the property file # i.e "2.property" "3.property" "4.property" etc....

I want to automate this, and still would like to see the results in the command prompt as it runs.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

See https://ss64.com/nt/for.html and specifically https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,4) DO program.bat -propertyfile "%%G.property"
```

Should run your command for files 1.property to 4.property but if you're actually running it for files in a directory rather than a list of integers one of the other FOR constructs might be more appropriate. Perhaps https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html